# Is it possible to make Country Code Picker Library look like material drop down menu (outlined)?

Tags: android, android-spinner, material-components-android

I'm creating an app which has google's material text input layout and I want to add country code dropdown in the app. I liked Country Code Picker Library but I want to make it look like the outlined box like other text fields. Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Check Screenshots :

How Country Code looks:

[image: How Country Code looks]

How I want it to look:

[image: How I want it to look]

Comment: Well, it depends on your implementation. How did you make it? Did you use some library?

Comment: clone the library, import it to your project and change it :D

Answer (score 0):

You can **override** a library UI by making an exact layout name used in the library. For example, if the library have the following layout:

```
layout_code_picker.xml
```

You need to create the same layout in your project with the same views `id` in the layout.

Or the last option, fork the library.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How can I find the layout file of the library? Can you explain or give me some kinda reference.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**. You can hide components of CCP if you need. Here is what I could achieve:

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/countryHolder"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:ccp_showArrow="false"
            app:ccp_showFlag="false"
            app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgClear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countryLabelTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:text="Country"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/countryHolder"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/countryHolder"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/countryHolder" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and here is used `rounded_corner.xml` drawable

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="8dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#555555" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

**here is my code **

```
  <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <!--<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/sign_mob_no"

                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:hint="Mobile Number"
                    android:inputType="phone">-->


                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="21dp">


                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                            android:id="@+id/mobile_no"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="start"
                            android:hint="Mobile Number"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                            app:counterMaxLength="5">


                            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                style="@style/loginfield"

                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_horizontal"


                                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                                android:inputType="phone"
                                android:maxEms="11"
                                android:maxLength="12"
                                android:maxLines="1"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textSize="16sp" />
                        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                    </RelativeLayout>


                    <com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker
                        android:id="@+id/ccp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:gravity="center|start"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        app:ccpDialog_backgroundColor="@color/white"
                        app:ccp_contentColor="@color/black"
                        app:ccp_countryAutoDetectionPref="SIM_NETWORK_LOCALE"
                        app:ccp_defaultPhoneCode="91"
                        app:ccp_hintExampleNumber="true"
                        app:ccp_showFlag="true"
                        app:ccp_showNameCode="false"
                        app:ccp_textSize="14dp">


                    </com.hbb20.CountryCodePicker>


                    <!--</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>-->
                </RelativeLayout>
```

**and add dependency. this worked for me  **

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28399299)